# Set C flags for xcframework Swift Package

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I have a complicated C library that I want to make available through Swift as a binary. I already have this setup with preprocessing header directives that check `#if defined(__iOS__)` for another project (a Flutter app). How can I define the `__iOS__` flag when using this C library through a Swift Package?

Here's what I tried:

1. Compile the C and create an xcframework
2. Include that xcframework as a binaryTarget in a Swift Package
3. Depend on that Swift Package with another Swift Package, with cSettings, like:

```
        .target(
            name: "Wrapper",
            dependencies: ["Framework"], cSettings: [.define("__iOS__")]]),
```

4. Add the Wrapper Swift Package to my Swift App.

My app can not process the headers because this `__iOS__` flag isn't getting used.

What is wrong with this approach? Or is there a standard way of solving this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're saying it has already been built as a binary library without the `__iOS__` preprocessor macro defined. If that's the case, it's too late to add it. That was evaluated before the compiler even saw the code and anything in an `#if` block was removed. Do you mean something else? The example you've shown here just defines `__iOS__` for Wrapper. It has nothing to do with Framework.

That said, typically in an xcframework you would build for different platforms and package them together. That's a big part of what an xcframework is for. So you can enable `__iOS__` for iOS platforms, and not for other platforms. See [Creating a multiplatform binary framework bundle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating-a-multi-platform-binary-framework-bundle) for details. But this needs to be done before you package the xcframework, not when you consume it.

Comment: The header files branch on `__iOS__`, and other flags. My xcframework was created for multiple platforms, compiled with this flag, but my Swift app still uses the header files. The particular error I'm seeing is an include file isn't available, because it isn't, it's in a non-`__iOS__` if-block.

Comment: Generally what you would do here is to create a `config.h` that your headers import, and define or don't define `__iOS__` in that header for appropriate platforms. Each platform gets its own copy of the headers for essentially this purpose. That way the consuming package doesn't need to do anything special.